# Dead centering a div within another div

Tags: html, css, center

I need your help,

How can I dead center a div within another div, both horizontally and vertically on page?

So far, I have managed to center my div horizontally.

Here's the HTML markup in question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>


    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgb(253,223,224);">

        <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">

                   some text here

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to give height http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/88Lqsgbo/ so that it will align center vertically

Comment: Here is great tutorial about this particular problem: [link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-holy-grail-of-css-centering--cms-22114)